# Angular: prevent auto recompile when there is a change in assets folder

Tags: html, angular, spring-boot, livereload

I'm trying to download a file generated from spring boot in the assets of the angular project. When I call the spring API from angular services, angular CLI recompiles the project after the creation of the file in assets angular folder, and then it reloads the page before getting the response from spring boot API.

I tried to call the spring boot API from angular in many ways:

- calling the api in the ngOnInit() of my component
- calling the api in the constructor of my component
- calling the api in a separate function
- using async await in the download function

I don't know ho to proceed

**spring boot**

```
 @GetMapping(path = "/downloads/{fileId}", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> download(@PathVariable String fileId){
        Gson gson = createGson();

        List<com.bioimis.blp.entity.File> fileById;

        try {
            fileById = fileRepository.findFileById(fileId);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null);
        }

        if (fileById.isEmpty()) {
            logger.error(fileId + " not found");
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null);
        }

        if(fileById.get(0).getDeletionDate() != null) {

            List<String> phrases = new ArrayList<>();

            try {
                phrases = translationRepository.getAllTranslationsByFileId(fileById.get(0).getId());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(null);
            }

            String file = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < phrases.size(); i++) {
                file = file.concat(phrases.get(i));
            }
            file = file.concat("\0");

            /*Suppongo che prima dell'estensione gli ultimi 5 caratteri del file sono in formato 'languageCode_countryCode'*/
            String nameFile = fileById.get(0).getPath().split("/")[fileById.get(0).getPath().split("/").length - 1];

            Language language;
            try {
                language = languageRepository.findLanguageById(fileById.get(0).getLanguageId()).get(0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null);
            }

            int i = StringUtils.lastIndexOf(nameFile, '.');
            String ext = StringUtils.substringAfter(nameFile, ".");

            nameFile = nameFile.substring(0, i - 5) + language.getLanguageCode() + "_" + language.getCountryCode() + "." + ext;

            Path path = Paths.get(pathDownload + "/" + nameFile);

            try {
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                Files.write(path, file.getBytes());
------------>after this instruction, angular reloads the page<---------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null);
            }

            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(gson.toJson(path.toString()));
        }

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(null);
    }
```

**Angular Component**

```
 downloadFile(fileId: string) {
    let link: string;

    this.http.downloadFile(fileId).subscribe(
      data => {
        link = data;
      }
    );

    console.log(link);
    return link;
  }
```

**Angular Service**

```
downloadFile(fileId: string) {
    const myheader = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', this.token);
    return this.http.get<string>(this.url.concat('files/downloads/' + fileId), { headers: myheader });
  }
```

I just expect to get the response from spring boot api without reloading the angular component.

(In postman it works as it has to be)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 reasons why this doesn't function at all:

- Binding the function in HTML component template makes infinite loop, that's a bad practice.
- Creating a file in assets where in Angular that's static folder, so every time that folder, or external folders linked in assets in `angular.json`, is updated with a new file, it reloads the component

I modified my download function that returns all the text of the file through the response and then I created a blob file (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-blob-file-download?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) where it will be downloaded when the user click the download button.

Answer (score 1):

Start the angular application as (instead of `ng serve`)

```
ng serve --live-reload false
```

> `--liveReload=true|false`  Whether to reload the page on change, using live-reload.
>
> **Default:** **true**

[Angular Commands](https://angular.io/cli/serve)

Alternatives

- `ng serve --no-live-reload`
- `ng serve --live-reload=false`
- create command in *package.json* as `"ng noreload" : "ng serve --live-reload=false"`

Comment: Good answer, but I still prefer to keep live reload

Comment: It doesn't solve the purpose, it doesn't showing the updated code changes in browser, it's just preserving the code changes nothing else. Any idea how to get effect in browser on code changes without refreshing the browser just only through websocket to refresh specific part only?